# Print out xml to the console (xml.etree.ElementTree)

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I need to print out xml to the console which I receive from a response:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET        

xml = req.text
result = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml))

rough_string = ET.tostring(result, "utf-8")
reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
print reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="\t")
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'
  File "....", line x, in ...
    rough_string = ET.tostring(result, "utf-8")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1126, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 820, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 900, in _serialize_xml
    tag = elem.tag
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

Comment: What is the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Also, don't feed Unicode text to XML parsers; always feed those a bytestring. It is the job of the parser to decode the data, based on the XML declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing an already created ElementTree object back to ElementTree:

```
result = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml))
```

Don't do that; remove the `ET.ElementTree()` call there:

```
result = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

Now your `ET.tostring()` call will work.

Next, I see you are using `req.text` as the source for your XML; if that is a `requests` response object then that is the *wrong* value to pass in, and you should be using `req.content` instead. The XML parser should be passed a *byte string*, not a `unicode` value. The parser will then decode based on the XML declaration. It may work for documents that contain nothing but ASCII text, but anything containing text beyond the ASCII character set will fail.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code sample:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

# Read XML file
data = ElementTree.parse('my.xml').getroot()

# Read String object
data = ElementTree. fromstring(my_xml_string).getroot()

# Print it in Console
ElementTree.dump(data)
```